# PHP File Creation File Extension Issues

Tags: php, mysql, file

I am using the script below to create an zipped (.tar.gz) .sql file of a mysql database (so I can then back the database file up). The problem is that when the file is created, for some reason the . in .sql and .tar.gz is not written properly and instead appears as a ? mark when I look at the file in terminal or any FTP program. Why is this script not properly creating a dot? Any advice? Could it be a language issue? My server is a VPS from Dreamhost and it's all in English.

Thanks!

```
<?php
ini_set("memory_limit","40M");

$dbhost = "host..."; 
$dbuser = "user...";
$dbpass = "pass...";
$dbname = "database...";

$backupfile = $dbname . ‘.sql’;
$backupzip = $backupfile . ‘.tar.gz’;
system("mysqldump -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname > $backupfile");
system("tar -czvf $backupzip $backupfile");

// Delete the unzipped file from the server
unlink($backupfile);

?>
```

Comment: it looks like you have some kind of weird single quotation marks around the file extensions. That could be what's causing your problem.

Comment: Brilliant. I can't believe I didn't notice this. Problem solved.

Do you want to add this in as an answer so you get the credit?

Comment: ok, I added it. Were you copying and pasting from somewhere? I'm just curious how that character got in there.

Comment: Yeah. I copied and pasted into a plain text editor so I didn't think it would be a problem. I'm surprised none of the other people that used the code had a problem with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you have some kind of weird single quotation marks around the file extensions. That could be what's causing your problem.